# Stroustrup's hash_map's implementation is wrong?

Tags: c++, hash, stl, hashmap

I'm looking at Straustrup's implementation of hash_map. This will give an intuition how he's implementing it

```
template<class Key, class T, class H = Hash<Key>, class EQ = equal_to<Key>, class A = allocator<T> >
class hash_map
{
private: // representation
    struct Entry {
        key_type key;
        mapped_type val;
        Entry* next; // hash overflow link
        bool erased;
        Entry(key_type k, mapped_type v, Entry* n)
        : key(k), val(v), next(n), erased(false) { }
    };

    vector<Entry> v; // the actual entries
    vector<Entry*> b; // the hash table: pointers into v
    // ...

private:
    float max_load; // keep v.size()<=b.size()*max_load
    float grow; // when necessary, resize(bucket_count()*grow)
    size_type no_of_erased; // number of entries in v occupied by erased elements
    Hasher hash; // hash function
    key_equal eq; // equality
    const T default_value; // default value used by []
};
```

And this is implementation of operator[]

```
template<class Key, class T, class H = Hash<Key>, class EQ = equal_to<Key>, class A = allocator<T> >
mapped_type& hash_map::operator[](const key_type& k)
{
    size_type i = hash(k)%b.size(); // hash
    for(Entry* p = b[i]; p; p = p->next) // search among entries hashed to i
        if (eq(k,p->key)) { // found
            if (p->erased) { // re-insert
                p->erased = false;
                no_of_erased--;
                return p->val = default_value;
            }
            return p->val;
        }

    // not found:
    if (b.size()*max_load < v.size()) { // if ‘‘too full’’
        resize(b.size()*grow); // grow
        return operator[](k); // rehash
    }

    v.push_back(Entry(k,default_value,b[i])); // add Entry
    b[i] = &v.back(); // point to new element
    return b[i]->val;
}
```

So, let's imagine there are 3 elements mapped to hash `i`, but none of them corresponds to the new key `k`, then we should add another Entry in the list `b[i]`, right? Instead the code creates another `Entry` in the `v` vector and replaces `b[i]` with the address of that entry (whence losing old 3 Entries).

Did I miss something, or really there is an issue?

P.S. I'm looking at "The C++ Programming language" by Bjarne Straustrup, Third edition. The function is on 500th page.

Comment: Why 3 elements? And how the 3 elements would have been there in the first place if each collision clobbers the previous one?

Comment: Yes maybe there couldn't be 3 elements, but there could be one element, and it will get lost, isn't it?

Comment: and there is no reason to use list of Entries, if Entries are never added to the list (at most one Entry in the list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hash entries form a linked list.  When the new entry is inserted, it is given the previous head of the list of entries (possibly null):

```
v.push_back(Entry(k,default_value,b[i])); // add Entry
```

See the `b[i]` there?

It then makes a link to that entry in its `next` field.  We then move the head of the list `b[i]` to point at the new entry;

```
b[i] = &v.back(); // point to new element
```